# How to increase max socket connections for Yosemite 10.10

Tags: network, tcp

I'm trying to test a network service app that allows for a large number of simultaneous socket connections.

I have adjusted `/etc/sysctl.conf` with the following:

```
kern.maxfiles=65536
kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
kern.ipc.somaxconn=10000
```

With this in place, `ulimit -n` shows I have a 65536 "open file" maximum. Yet my service still gets stuck around the 1000th connection.

Thinking that perhaps it's something specific to the platform (Node), I re-implemented a simplified version of it in Golang, but it exhibits the same problem.

It also happens if I split the "client" side up into several procs that each open a handful of connections. The service always get stuck around the 1000th connection.

`lsof -p <pid>` shows 1011 IPv6 connections like so:

```
gochat  25034 username  178u    IPv6 0x11c1273e19ee5c8f       0t0       TCP localhost:http-alt->localhost:50080 (ESTABLISHED)
```

What is imposing this maximum socket connection limit, and how can I expand it?

Comment: how about this one http://blog.whatsapp.com/196/1-million-is-so-2011

Comment: @buscar- looks promising, but doesn't work on OSX: 
sysctl: unknown oid 'kern.ipc.numopensockets'

Comment: how about this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/9676852 ) on Linux server. And this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/7580233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the Go [socketio library](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io)  has a default max setting of 1000 simultaneous socket connections. Calling `server.SetMaxConnection(10000)` (in conjunction with an appropriately high `ulimit -n`, as mentioned in the question) will allow > 1000 simultaneous client connections.